# Android RelativeLayout position items

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-relativelayout

The following image is what I'm trying to reach as final result:
[image]

My code so far works great on aligning the buttons in center:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

     <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_A"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/my_border"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/categories" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_B"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_A"
        android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/my_border"
        android:src="@drawable/shopping_cart" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Then, after the "button_B" I tried to achieve the message "TEXT HERE IN CENTER" without success.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/txt" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TEXT HERE IN CENTER"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

**Edit:** Solved. http://pastebin.com/9DwaQrPq

Comment: Depending on what the rest of this layout should do, you really don't need two relative layouts. So you're not getting the text at all, or it's not centered?

Comment: @Sualkcin it's not centered and if I put the textview like I told in the post, the imagesbuttons stay out of the center.

Answer (score 0):

add the attributes

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:layout_below="id of thing you want it below"
```

to the text view

also take the text view out of the inner `Relative Layout`

**EDIT**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/itemRoot"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:clickable="false">

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button_A"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/my_border"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:src="@drawable/categories" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button_B"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_A"
    android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:background="@drawable/my_border"
    android:src="@drawable/shopping_cart" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: See my answer to @codeMagic. I tried with your solution (adding the layout_below) and I get the same result.

Comment: @user2742861 add the layout_gravity=centre attribute to The image buttons too

Comment: doesn't work either. The ImageButtons don't have Layout_gravity attribute. My current layout is the first image I post in my topic without the "TEXT HERE", I didn't find yet a solution.

Comment: @user2742861 try adding `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` to your `ImageButtons` if that doesnt work wrap them in a `LinearLayout` like above (edited answer)

Answer (score 0):

Take your `TextView` out of this inner `RelativeLayout` and give it the property and add a `gravity` to it to center your text.

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/txt" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="TEXT HERE IN CENTER"/>
```

If this doesn't work then please explain what you are getting or what isn't working about it. Also, a picture of what you currently are getting would help.

**Edit**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

 <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button_A"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/my_border"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:src="@drawable/categories" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button_B"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_A"
    android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:background="@drawable/my_border"
    android:src="@drawable/shopping_cart" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/txt" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="TEXT HERE IN CENTER"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: With your solution, my final code is: http://pastebin.com/hbJqs4q4
And I get this output: http://s24.postimg.org/tvi45r9n9/Sem_T_tulo.png

So, the ImagesButtons get of the middle.

Comment: Wrap your `ImageButton`s in a `LinearLayout` and add `android:layout_centerInParent="horizontal"` to the `LinearLayout`

Comment: Hello. With your solution It's even worst..or I didn't get what you're trying to say. If I use the LinearLayout and put those ImageButtons inside that LinearLayout I stop being able of using properties like: layout_toRightOf, etc. which are very important, and all my ImageButtons stays out of the center the way I want (displayed in the first image).

Comment: See my edit. Something like that is what I meant. You may need to tweak some properties a little if necessary. But that should get you close if I understand what you want.

Comment: thanks. I managed to get this working this way: http://pastebin.com/9DwaQrPq, let me know if it's the best way.

Comment: Ummm...I think so. Isn't that how I said in my edit? I just left out the other two `ImageButton`s because those weren't in your original code.

Comment: I didn't know that only two buttons should be on LinearLayout and the others out of it.

Comment: To be honest, I'm a little confused because you only showed two `Button`s in your xml but your picture looks like there is 8. On a question like this, you need to post your *complete* `layout`. Anyway, I guess if you got it working that's all that matters.